# Can Linear Maps be Continuous/Differentiable on Non-Complete Vector Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

Let $E,F$ be normed vector spaces, and let $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ be the set of linear maps from $E$ to $F$.

All the definitions of linear maps being continuous (and differentiable) that I have seen require that  $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces (i.e., complete normed vector spaces).

> Why is this necessary? If $E$ or $F$ is not Banach, are there no linear maps from $E$ to $F$ that are continuous/differentiable?

Comment: A linear operator between normed space is continuous if and only if it is bounded. So there are many continuous linear operators. As for why people usually restrict to Banach spaces, there could be many reasons. Convergence of all Cauchy sequences can be useful for proving that a sequence converges even when you don't know its limit. You get the open mapping theorem, closed graph theorem, and then bounded inverse theorem (If $T \colon E \to F$ is continuous and bijective, then $T^{-1}$ is continuous).

Comment: But the definitions of the total derivative don't change if the spaces are not Banach? (I wasn't sure if that was a necessary condition for differentiability of multilinear maps)

Comment: The definition of the derivative does not change (the derivative can be defined for topological vector spaces, you do not even need a norm), but I think perhaps you can not prove so many useful things about it unless you're in a complete space.